# How do I fix a hole in an interior block wall?

Tags: walls, brick, hole-repair

Whilst doing some kitchen renovation I noticed a rather large hole in a cinder block wall the size of half a block. It seems that it was done with a lump hammer in order to plumb in some pipes. There are also two cracks emanating from the hole.

The hole is on a wall that supports the stairs.

[image: Hole]

How should I go about fixing the problem?

Comment: What's the purpose of the electrical wire going into the wall?  What is the end of the wire connected to inside the wall?

Comment: Is all the wiring and plumbing shown normally hidden behind cabinets or something?  From the looks of the crack, this hole is in a covering layer, not in a cinder block proper.  I might mesh&plaster to avoid drafts and rodent entry, but otherwise fuggeddabbadit.

Answer (score 1):

This wall does look more like plasterboard/plaster & lathe than it does any sort of cinder block/[Concrete Masonry Unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_masonry_unit) (CMU). The wall cavity just isn't thick enough for a CMU before there's what looks like a finished wall on the other side.

If that's the case, I'd suggest cutting back the rough edges until you find some sort of stud (on each side), then do a simple plaster board repair on the wall. There should be plenty of examples here of how to do that, but if you can't find an explanation that makes enough sense to you, ask a new question and indicate your specific stumbling block.

Comment: And no one would be concerned about the heavy extension cord being sealed into the wall?

Comment: No telling where that goes, @Programmer66. I presumed it would simply go though the hole. Of course, there's no telling whether the current installation meets code, wherever OP is located...

Comment: That appears (on the close-up view) to be two cables, not an extension cord, and whether the install is considered acceptable to local code would depend on a locale that is almost certainly one where I don't know the code that well. The wall may also be a 4" or perhaps 90-100 mm block, rather than the 6-8" FreeMan is expecting.